# Xcode build fails with Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, arm64, github-ci

I got the following warning on Github CI when trying to build an iOS archive:

```sh
ld: warning: ignoring file ios/myframework.xcframework/ios-arm64/myframework.framework/myframework, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-unsupported file format ( 0x76 0x65 0x72 0x73 0x69 0x6F 0x6E 0x20 0x68 0x74 0x74 0x70 0x73 0x3A 0x2F 0x2F )
```

then this error followed:

```sh
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
```

Now the confusing thing is that this error can happen because of several reasons, in my case, it was neither of any I could find online.

Answer (score 14):

After hours of debugging I was able to figure out that the unknown-unsupported file format warning appeared because I was using Git LFS for the framework's binary. Git LFS replaces the binary with a text pointer. When Xcode was trying to build my archive on the CI, it didn't pull the binary from LFS, hence the string pointer remained at `ios/myframework.xcframework/ios-arm64/myframework.framework/myframework`. Make sure to pull your large binaries from LFS before trying to setup an Xcode build on the CI or you might see some not-so-easy-to-debug issues like this.

So the solution was actually as easy as running `git lfs pull` before trying to build the archive, and voilá, the error was gone.

Comment: i'm trying with your solution, but still same issue. Could you please help me, i'm facing same issue. Please check the attached question. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70972588/fastlane-mapbox-framework-architecture-arm64-symbol
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70942325/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-arm64-ios

Comment: Answered in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70972588/fastlane-mapbox-framework-architecture-arm64-symbol/71034157#71034157

Comment: Bingo, had to open my project in Sourcetree and it asked me to do exactly this.

Comment: I actually ran into the same situation. Unbelieveable!
It's so important to check all your preparation work in script including stuff like git-lfs!

Comment: Damn. Neat solution. Thanks !!

Comment: I ran into a similar situation whereby the binary within my `.framework` had been corrupted by being decompressed with [node-tar](https://github.com/isaacs/node-tar) – in the particular setup, it was being decoded as UTF-8 rather than as binary.